# search in the second column of a cell array by the value of the first column

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I'm working in MATLAB and I have the following cell array:

```
pippo = 

'FSize'           [       10]
'MSize'           [       10]
'rho'             [      997]
'u2'              [  86.2262]
'n'               [      100]
'nimp'            [        2]
'impeller1dir'    [1x66 char]
'impeller2dir'    [1x66 char]
'comparedir'      [1x57 char]
```

I would like to return the content of the cell, in the second column, which corresponds to a given value for the cell in the first column of the first row. I.e., if the input is 'nimp', I want to return 2.
Is there a simple way to do this which doesn't involve looping, or is looping the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods to do this are `containers.Map` and `logical indexing`

---

### Logical indexing

firstly we will find the occurance of the input in the first column with `strcmp` using `ind=strcmp(pippo(:,1),'nimp')` and then get the contents of the cell in the second column where this is true `pippo{ind,2}`

which can be combined into one line with

```
out = pippo{strcmp(pippo(:,1),'nimp'),2}
```

---

### containers.Map

using `containers.Map` you can map the keys in the first column to the values in the second column this information is stored as a container, below this is the pippo2 variable

```
pippo2=containers.Map(pippo(:,1),pippo(:,2))
```

and then you can call the container with an argument of the key and get the value as output

```
out=pippo2('nimp')

out =

     2
```

Comment: Amazing! I tried logical indexing, but this way: `ind=pippo(:,1)=='nimp'` and this way: `ind=pippo(:,1)=='nimp'`. However, neither worked. I didn't think about strcmp! The containers.Map trick is neat, too. Thanks a lot!